# ListView - scroll an item so it touches top of view?

Tags: android

Possible? I know there's smoothScrollToPosition() (in api >= 8), but that doesn't make the requested element touch the top of the listview. It just says that the item will be visible.

I imagine I could measure each item somehow and set the scroll position manually, this doesn't help on my last few rows though, since those should not be allowed to scroll to the top anyway.

Use case - I want me users to pop open the keyboard and comment on an item in my ListView. The ime keyboard will cover some portion of the screen, so I want the 'focused' row to be touching the top of the view so they remember what they're commenting on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add a big & empty footerView when your user open the keyboard.
and remove the footerview when user close the keyboard.
if you add a big footerview, you can use `ListView.SetSelection(last_row_pos)`
After that, the last row will touch top of view.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a set of flags in your manifest under your activity element which will allow you to do this. Please check the docs to see what your various options are.